# Eager Loading EF

Tags: entity-framework

I'm an absolute beginner on EF, and I am stuck at what probably is very simple.

I have 2 tables/classes:
Toys and Brands

```
public class Toys
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
}
public class Brands
{
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
    public string BrandName { get; set; }
}
```

My DBContext file:

```
public class SOT : DbContext
{ public SOT(): base("name=SOT")
    {

public virtual DbSet<Brands> brands; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Toys> toys { get; set; }
}
```

When I add a record, the BrandId goes to the BrandId field in the Toys table.

I want to display in the view the Name of the toy, and the Brand Name. Now I get toy name and Brand Id

In my controller, on the Index Action:

```
public ViewResult Index()
    {
/// this is where I am sooo stuck.....
        var toy = _context.Toys.Include(c => c.Brands).ToList();
        return View(toy);
    }
```

The view:

```
<td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BrandName)
    </td>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't add any relations. `Toy` (not Toys, it's not a table or list of values) should have a `Brand` attribute. This way you can display the brand name with `item.Brand.BrandName`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : yes you are right. Adding the brand attribute did the trick to show the brandname in the view. However, when I now enter a new record, the BrandId int is entered in the toys table, but the (new) field that refers to the Brand remains empty. I can manually select the entries in the table, and then I see that result in the view. Performing the _context.Toys.Add shows the Id with a value, but the Brandfield as null. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this will helps you, If you make a relation between Toy and Brand Table

```
var q = _context.Toys
         .Select(q_toys =>
         new
         {
            q_toys.Name,
            q_toys.Brand.BrandName 
         }).ToList();
```